# Is this a bug? emacs freezes when doing "sudo service apache2 status" inside a org babel tramp remote code block

Tags: org-babel, tramp, terminal-emacs

I think I've found a bug with emacs+org+babel.
This block runs fine

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:ubuntu@54.175.231.31:~/ :exports both :results output                                
sudo service --status-all                                                                                  
#+END_SRC
```

This block freezes emacs

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:ubuntu@54.175.231.31:~/ :exports both :results output                                
sudo service apache2 status                                                                                   
#+END_SRC
```

[image]

This is the expected output

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-188:~$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-4-188:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely, there is a problem in handling the password of the sudo command. Try

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:ubuntu@54.175.231.31|sudo:54.175.231.31:~/ :exports both :results output
service apache2 status
#+END_SRC
```

The sudo password is handled by Tramp then. This works for me, at least.

Comment: but, "sudo service --status-all" works....

Comment: on an Amazon EC2 ubuntu vm, the ubuntu user is a privileged "sodoer" , so no prompts to sudo.

Comment: Have you tried whether the recipe works? This is what counts.

Comment: No luck. same deal. Last thing printed in echo area is "Wrote /ssh:ubuntu@54.90.109.247|sudo:root@54.90.109.247:/tmp/ob-input-OlELLu" before emacs freezes

Comment: You could try to trace Tramp, by setting `tramp-verbose` to 10. But I fear it won't help, because the freezing is in the command out of Tramp control.